# Font aligned to top of box in pc and to bottom in mac

Tags: css, fonts, size, line

I have an `h2` with a `@font-face` font.
For some reason, on a mac the font is aligned to the top of the `h2` as you can see here:

[image]

and on the pc it is aligned to the top:

[image]

I tried giving them `line-height`, `height` and `width` and nothing made the alignment the same. Any ideas why?

Comment: @IlyaD Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: @HenrikAmmer tried only in chrome, don't care about others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `vertical-align:baseline;` or `vertical-align:text-top;`.

Edit: This probably won't work.
Check [this](http://www.icavia.com/2010/09/solving-font-face-alignment-issues/) out instead.

Comment: thanx, the solution from the article worked, I hoped I won't have to resort to platform detection but seems like there is no way around it...